# convert from unsigned char to char*

Tags: c

I have a function that currently returns `unsigned char`. However, I want to cast that `unsigned char` to a `char*` but I keep getting cast to/from pointer from/to integer of different size warning.

Let `foo` be the function that return an unsigned char

I tried something like this:

```
char* convert = (char*)foo();
```

The reason for converting to `char*` is because I need to use the `strcasecmp` function to perform a string compare.

Comment: Why do you need to convert an integer value of 8 bits into a pointer value of 32 bits (32 bits architecture)? Please add more details on your question.

Comment: The reason for converting to char* is because I need to use the strcasecmp function to perform a string compare.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? The char* must point to an array consisting at least of that char, and a trailing nul byte.

Comment: No worries guy, I got it!

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast a non-pointer function return value into a pointer at all. Think about it, where would this pointer point to?

You can, however, save the result to a variable and have a pointer to it.
For example,

```
 char tmp = (char) foo();
 char * ptr = &tmp;
```

Edit:

As another answer said, if you want to use `strcasecmp` you would need a `char` array where the last byte is the null terminator.

Comment: That is more like it man! Thanks, I totally forget that!! havent really work with pointer for awhile!!! I am currently working on a firewall project in C while at the same time working on a PHP project for a database class. So I basically have not touch pointer for a while until now. You refresh my mind!! thanks again man!

Comment: To be honest, that doesn't fill the users of firewall products with confidence.

Comment: @gnasher729 the php and c are two separate project... in my questions I didnt even give an indication of how it all work with the firewall, i just stick my question to what i merely want to acheive. By no mean I am making a firewall product for public use just for a class project.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, use the following code:

```
char array [2];
array [0] = (char) foo ();
array [1] = '\0';
...
... strcasecmp (array, ...);
```

This builds an array containing a string of a single character which you can then use.